# How to change the background color of only the left and right side of a page?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to work out how to change the color of the left and right side of my website, so it looks a little better
[image: This is what my website currently looks like]

This is my main app code

```
<template>
  <div>
 <Header/>
  <NavBar/>
  <router-view/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar.vue"
import Header from "./components/Header.vue"

export default {
components: {Header, NavBar}
}
</script>
<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-left: 800px;
 background: black;
}

body{
background-color: black;
}
```

I have tried adding columns and rows, however I can't seem to work out how to make them stretch down the entire page and changing the background color that way.

Comment: Please [import](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) your project to codesandbox to create a *runnable* [mcve]. Without one, the chances of getting a useful answer are null, as you haven't included enough code to repro.

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1

One thing you can do is to make your background color of body to something and then for your container change it back to white. Also if you want to make both sides of different color your can use [CSS Gradient](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp).

### Method 2

There are some other approaches like making 3 different columns in your page and then adding content in center column and other two columns go with your color but that would be a mess.

Comment: That first method is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much